# Change the speed of a single unchanging sprite object in pygame

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes, pygame

I am doing a pygame program from a book where a chef drops pizzas and you have to catch them with a pan. The chef and pan sprites are only created once, while the pizza sprites obviously keep getting created. I am trying to make it so that as the score gets higher, the chef starts to move around faster (only moves in the x). I think I am running into trouble with class attributes vs instance attributes. I have been unable to find a way to access the score from the chef class, even though I tried making score a global variable or even just assigning it to a dummy global variable (This would allow me to make changes to the chefs speed within the update method). Alternatively, I tried accessing the chefs dx within the pan class since that is where the score is. I have also been unable to access that, even with the getattr method. Would greatly appreciate any suggestions on this one. Here is the code for the pan and chef class. I have commented out parts of stuff that I tried and didn't work.

```
from livewires import games, color
import random

games.init(screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)


class Pan(games.Sprite):
    """
    A pan controlled by player to catch falling pizzas.
    """
    image = games.load_image("pan.bmp")

    def __init__(self):
        """ Initialize Pan object and create Text object for score. """
        super(Pan, self).__init__(image = Pan.image,
                                  x = games.mouse.x,
                                  bottom = games.screen.height)


        self.score = games.Text(value = 0, size = 25, color = color.black,
                                top = 5, right = games.screen.width - 10)
        games.screen.add(self.score)

    def update(self):
        """ Move to mouse x position. """
        self.x = games.mouse.x

        if self.left < 0:
            self.left = 0

        if self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.right = games.screen.width

        self.check_catch()
    def check_catch(self):
        """ Check if catch pizzas. """
        for pizza in self.overlapping_sprites:
            self.score.value += 10

#increase the speed of the pizza

 #           if self.score.value % 100 == 0:
#             Pizza.speed += 0.1
     #           print(Pizza.speed)

#increase the speed of the chef


   #         if self.score.value % 100 == 0:
     #          print(Chef.dx)
      #         print(x)
       #        y = int(x)*2
        #       print(y)

            self.score.right = games.screen.width - 10 
            pizza.handle_caught()




class Chef(games.Sprite):
    """
    A chef which moves left and right, dropping pizzas.
    """
    image = games.load_image("chef.bmp")
    speed  = 2

    def __init__(self, y = 55, odds_change = 200):
        """ Initialize the Chef object. """
        super(Chef, self).__init__(image = Chef.image,
                                   x = games.screen.width / 2,
                                   y = y,
                                   dx = Chef.speed)

        self.odds_change = odds_change
        self.time_til_drop = 0

    def update(self):
        #x = getattr(Pan,"score")
        #print(x)
        """ Determine if direction needs to be reversed. """
        if self.left < 0 or self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        elif random.randrange(self.odds_change) == 0:
           self.dx = -self.dx       
        self.check_drop()


    def check_drop(self):
        """ Decrease countdown or drop pizza and reset countdown. """
        if self.time_til_drop > 0:
            self.time_til_drop -= 1
        else:
            new_pizza = Pizza(x = self.x)
            games.screen.add(new_pizza)

            # set buffer to approx 30% of pizza height, regardless of pizza speed   
            self.time_til_drop = int(new_pizza.height * 1.3 / Pizza.speed) + 1      


def main():
    """ Play the game. """
    wall_image = games.load_image("wall.jpg", transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = wall_image

    the_chef = Chef()
    games.screen.add(the_chef)

    the_pan = Pan()
    games.screen.add(the_pan)

    games.mouse.is_visible = False

    games.screen.event_grab = True
    games.screen.mainloop()

# start it up!
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the chef speed is a class variable you need to add the class name to access it, as in: `Chef.speed`.  Where is the pizza class?  I don't know Livewire so can't explain why you can't access the score, but surely you can set it as a number somehow and use it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time. I was able to solve it by creating an attribute flag within the Pan class to check the score and then accessing that attribute flag in the Chef's update method, to then be able to change dx. Chef.speed is only the initial chef speed so changing it doesn't update the chef's dx.